# API hook detection

Tags: api, hook

Is there any way to identify the processes hooked to a particular dll?

For example, 
When a malware infects, it does api hooking such as to "InternetConnect function" in  "Wininet.dll". 
So, how to detect these hooked programs for a particular api ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you may be looking for is the one posted here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/what-are-the-methods-to-find-hooked-functions-and-apis

Basically, the short version of that is that if you want to check for common ways of user-level API hooking, you could try to:

- compare code in the binary file to the code in memory
- compare IAT start-up snapshot to current IAT.
- compare the code pointed to be the known entries of the IAT to the actual entries

[This paper](http://www.autosectools.com/IAT-Hooking-Revisited.pdf) is also recommended as a very good resource for this question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for it manually, use Dependency Walker to look for the dlls the executable refers to (static links) or for runtime, use process explorer (sysinternals) and check the loaded modules (dlls) in the memory and their signatures for that process.

Search google for both the tools, you will find it free and easy to use.

Process Monitor is one of the other sysinternals tools if you are interested to attach to a process and look for all activities of a process (like file system calls, registry calls, etc).